# Why the last goroutine starts first in a loop with two goroutines?

Tags: go, mutex, goroutine

I have been doing some tests with goroutines and I noticed a weird behaviour (for me) using this code:

Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/Py4oqGqkYKm

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sync"
)
var (
    mu sync.Mutex
    wg sync.WaitGroup
)

func main() {
    var x int
    for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
        wg.Add(2)
        go func() {
            mu.Lock()
            x = i
            mu.Unlock()
            wg.Done()
        }()
        go func() {
            mu.Lock()
            fmt.Print("x: ", x, " \n")
            mu.Unlock()
            wg.Done()
        }()
        wg.Wait()
    }
}
```

I have expected as output something such as:

```sh
x: 0 
x: 1 
x: 2 
x: 3 
x: 4 
x: 5 
x: 6 
x: 7 
x: 8 
x: 9
```

But I have received:

```sh
x: 0 
x: 0 
x: 1 
x: 2 
x: 3 
x: 4 
x: 5 
x: 6 
x: 7 
x: 8
```

It looks like that the second goroutines is called first (like LIFO). Thinking that, I have tried to invert the goroutines and I received the answer that I have expected:

Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/BC1r3NK6RBm

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sync"
)

var (
    mu sync.Mutex
    wg sync.WaitGroup
)

func main() {
    var x int
    for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
        wg.Add(2)
        go func() {
            mu.Lock()
            fmt.Print("x: ", x, " \n")
            mu.Unlock()
            wg.Done()
        }()
        go func() {
            mu.Lock()
            x = i
            mu.Unlock()
            wg.Done()
        }()
        wg.Wait()
    }
}
```

Output:

```sh
x: 0 
x: 1 
x: 2 
x: 3 
x: 4 
x: 5 
x: 6 
x: 7 
x: 8 
x: 9
```

Could anyone help me to understand this behavior?

Go version:
`go version go1.16.2 linux/amd64`

Comment: @PenelopeStevens this comment was useful to understand better... We can not control which mutex will be called first, right? So, Attending what I wanna do, I need to use channels like that: https://play.golang.org/p/OVK4hTQSu_d Right?

Comment: The whole point of "concurrent processes" is that their relative order is not defined.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Go Language does not specify the order that goroutines execute outside of explicit synchronization using channels, mutexes, wait groups and so on.  The specification allows for both outputs from both programs.

You are observing the order that the mutex is acquired, not the order that the goroutines start. It could be that the goroutines start in your expected order, but the unexpected goroutine calls Lock() first.

The only ordering ensured by the program is through the wait group:  Each pair of goroutines will complete before the next pair is started.

Answer (score 0):

The Go routines provide concurrency and work on top of share heap allocation with independent stack memory. The purpose of them is to provide concurrent execution on top of multi-core systems. There in no governing factor to how they are executed in parallel. This is decided by the actual processor. We only use the processor through layers of abstraction.

There is actually no concurrent system where you can govern/predict the outcome.

Comment: "This is decided by the actual processor." --- doesn't Go runtime decide that?